# Running a Java Swing Application by double click (w/o console)

Tags: java, swing, logging, jar

Suppose I have an executable JAR that launches a Swing GUI. If it is launched from the console (e.g. `java -jar myapp`) then the console is also used by the application (i.e. logs are being printed). This logging takes a bit time, it's quite verbose.

Note, that I only have a JAR, not the sources.

**Question:** what happens when you *double-click run* a JAR? Obviously no logs are visible, but are they simply invisible, or does this indeed boost the performance of the application (by skipping logging)?

Comment: What happens when you do it? Do you see notice a difference in speed?

Comment: It's hard to say, in both cases the operation lasts 1-2 seconds..

Comment: 1 or 2 seconds? Why don't you measure with the logs and the console, then with the logs and without a console, then without the logs at all. That would tell you if you need to care about it or not.

Comment: This is a general question (does the console slow down apps) - not about any particular application.

Comment: Then the answer is yes, it slows it down. Executing an instruction that is not needed takes more time than not executing it at all. And painting things on the screen takes more time than not doing it.

Comment: In other words: if I write `System.out.println("test");` and no console window is present, then does the operation execute - write to some stream that is not displayed, or does the JVM skip such an instruction knowing that std out is invisible?

Comment: Yes, the operation is executed. The OS decides where stdout must go. You could pipe the output to another process, or redirect it to a file, and the JVM doesn't know about it. Writing to the console is slower than writing to a file, which is slower than writing to nowhere.

Comment: Okay, so as far as JVM is concerned, `println` to a console window and to "nothing" is seen exactly the same? BTW. please form all this chat as an answer so I can accept it on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.prinln()` prints to the output stream of the process. The JVM doesn't know and care about where the output actually goes. It could be the console, or it could be redirected to a file, or piped to another process, or sent to nowhere. The instruction is a blocking operation, so the time taken by the instruction depends on where it actually goes. Printing to a console is slower than printing to a file, which is slower than printing to nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to see the console, use `javaw` to launch the program instead of `java`.  So you would run: `javaw -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: I didn't know about `javaw`, +1 :-)

Comment: @elmes javaw is the program used to run the jar when you double click on it too!

Answer (score 3):

If your intention is to stop logging, you can turn your logging off with `Logger#setLevel(Level.OFF)` (assuming you are using the standard logger). If your intention is to reduce the verbosity of your log messages, you can use Level.WARNING for example, for which only WARNING and SEVERE messages get logged. Generally you can set the minimum level to be logged to any level.
When your app is launched without a console, it usually has no `Console` attached to it (but I think this is a platform issue, for example, some platforms may provide central consoles I think while Java web apps running in servlet containers even if the container was started from a console usually don't have attached Console) so I won't bet my code on that for any reason.
If you still want your logs in an app that wouldn't have an attached `Console` in runtime, you can always redirect your log messages to a file using `Logger#addHandler(FileHandler)`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually `System.out.println()` is not preferred for logging. It is an IO-operation and time consuming. If you need turn off, need to comment manually in code.

Use log4j or java Logger.

Comment: How does log4j write logs to console if not by an IO-operation?

Comment: @elmes: what vels4j means, I think, is that using a logging, you don't need to comment out any line of code to switch logging off and avoid this costly IO operation.

Comment: I fully understand this, but I guess it doesn't matter what logging library you use - they all end up using standard I/O (if they are configured to write to console). Moreover, some libraries (eg. log4j) may concatenate logged `String`s even if the logging level is below the required - this is costly.

Comment: @JBNizet I've said, need comment like //System.out.print() not for logger. Also in logger can use `Level`s like FINE,INFO,DEBUG etc., and mean it vels4j like log4j :-)